# Example in Help File does not evaluate as claimed

Tags: special-functions, documentation

In the help file, under `BellB`, I read at "Properties and Relations":

> `Sum` can give results involving `BellB`:
>
> ```
> Sum[k^n/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}]  
>    E BellB[n]
> ```

but, in my version 10.0.1.0 it does not do as claimed. Neither does Wolfram Alpha.

Question: did it work in previous versions?

Comment: The example behave the same (i.e. does *not* return BellB) in v9 on Win 7.

Comment: Works on v7.0.1 on a Mac but not v8, v9, or v10.

Comment: Sum[k^n/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}] returns E BellB[n]

Comment: @ulvi: well done. It should be seen as an improvement over v7.0.1. Brings up the question of 'when do we obtain a conditional result' like `Integrate[x^n, {x, 0, 1}]` giving `ConditionalExpression[(1 + n)^(-1), Re[n] > -1]` ?